# How do I represent features with multiple values for one datapoint?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree

I am building a model and have features that have multiple values and I'm at a loss for how to represent it. For example, if I'm trying to predict the price of a t-shirt and I have a feature "color", what do I do if I have a shirt that is blue and yellow? If I put blue-yellow, would that be considered different than yellow-blue? Would the model capture that there is a blue component and yellow component to blue-yellow?

My understanding is that the model would view blue-yellow, yellow-blue, blue and yellow as 4 different colors and would not understand any connection between them.

I'm considering converting the values to binary or something similar, like:

(yellow, blue, green, red)
(1,0,0,0) -> yellow
(1,1,0,0) -> yellow and blue

But I'm not seeing how yellow and yellow-blue would have any connection still? If there is a general direction to explore or concept that I'm not understanding, please let me know so I can inform myself. Thank you

I am working in R using decision trees and random forests.

I had 2 separate features, "color 1" and "color 2"; but the model was not capturing that "color 1" and "color 2" as the same feature, so if I had color 1 = blue and color 2 = yellow that would not be the same as vice versa since the model doesn't know that the features "color 1" and "color 2" are related at all.

Comment: Why not instead of `color1` and `color2` have `blue` and `yellow` as the column names and have the the data `1,0` for blue, then `0,1` for yellow `and `1,1` for blue/yellow combination?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have 30+ colors. Staying with this example, I also have 30+ material types it can be.

Comment: At one point the colors whether mixed or not, must be in each column as the treatment contrast dictates so. I am not sure of a way to model a factor with huge amount of levels. But you can do a Google search to see how to tackle that